# Is the way to run in Ride tests based on robot framework library writen on python 3.6?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

Official docs says that Ride is not supported py 3.x, but plugin can run that tests. Any instructions about setup this test workflow?
Now when I run *.robot tests based on the keyword library writen on py 3.x I have  failed: ImportError and failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Any ideas will helps.

Comment: the test runner supports multiple run profiles, including running your own script. Have you tried creating a custom profile? It's not very well documented, but here's a starting point: https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Test-Runner-Plugin

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks! I viewd this page and asking exactly about this. Is this only way to run robot3 tests based by py3 library?? I viewed runner's standard profile scripts but not idea how to create custom. Example's, detailed documentation, pages, some experience? Asking not for code, but some info how to do.

Comment: @Verv hope my previos comment is helpful to understand question.

Comment: @Verv for clearify question. My question: Is the way to run in Ride(ide) tests(on robotframework) based on robot framework library(py file) writen on python 3.6(version)?

If the only way - custom script runner in Ride, can you provide your experience for add some detatils to runner's small documentation.